# How to sort the frequency of each letter in a descending order Python?

Tags: python, string, sorting, counter, python-collections

```py
import collections

MY_FUN_STR = filter(str.isalpha, (str.lower("ThE_SLATe-Maker")))

frequencies = collections.Counter(MY_FUN_STR)

a = sorted(frequencies, reverse=True)

for letter in frequencies:
    print ('{} appears {}'.format(letter, frequencies[letter]) + " times")
```

The output now is:

```
t appears 2 times
h appears 1 times
e appears 3 times
s appears 1 times
l appears 1 times
a appears 2 times
m appears 1 times
k appears 1 times
r appears 1 times
```

Comment: Your output is coming from the unsorted `frequencies` rather than the sorted `a`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You're sorting the output from the counter, but never actually using it inside the subsequent `for` loop.
2. Your sorting is based on lexicographical ordering, *not* the frequency of the actual keys. You need to pass in an explicit `key` parameter to `sorted()`, so that the function knows to sort based on frequency.

Here is a code snippet that resolves both of these issues:

```py
import collections

MY_FUN_STR = filter(str.isalpha, (str.lower("ThE_SLATe-Maker")))

frequencies = collections.Counter(MY_FUN_STR)

a = sorted(frequencies, key=lambda x: frequencies[x], reverse=True)

for letter in a:
    print ('{} appears {}'.format(letter, frequencies[letter]) + " times")
```

This prints the following:

```
e appears 3 times
t appears 2 times
a appears 2 times
h appears 1 times
s appears 1 times
l appears 1 times
m appears 1 times
k appears 1 times
r appears 1 times
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in you code.

1. `dictionary` is not ordered (though in some latest python versions it do preserve the order you add to it), so sorting it makes no sense actually. When you apply `sorted` to a `dictionary`, it returns the keys `list`. Considering you need both `key` and `value` in the print, sorting `.items()` is better choice. example:

```py
d = {'b': 2, "a": 1}
print(sorted(d))
# ['a', 'b']
print(sorted(d.items()))
# [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

2. `sorted` function has a `key` parameter, which is often a lambda expression indicating what property of the item to order by. If not specified, will sort by `dictionary.key` by default, but in your case you want sort by `dictionary.value`, so you need the `key=` parameter.
3. Sorted object is never used.

```py
import collections

MY_FUN_STR = filter(str.isalpha, (str.lower("ThE_SLATe-Maker")))
frequencies = collections.Counter(MY_FUN_STR)
sorted_key_value_items = sorted(frequencies.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
for letter, count in sorted_key_value_items:
    print('{} appears {}'.format(letter, count) + " times")
```

Reference this answer to sort a dict: [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: Applying `sorted` to a dictionary produces a list.  Your code and the OP's are no different in that regard.

Comment: thanks, i updated the answer to reflect your opinion. i think the `sorted` function is smart enough ^_^.